# How to disable "Is network trusted?" popup on wifi connection in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, ssl-certificate, mdm

I'm developing android app with device owner rights which can apply some system settings for android system.
Now I'm trying to setup wifi certificate and make wifi connection via my application. I'm using `WifiConfiguration` class and some other features (pseudo code):

```
// Creating enterprise config
val enterpriseConfig = WifiEnterpriseConfig()
...
enterpriseConfig.caCertificate = caCertificate
enterpriseConfig.enableTrustOnFirstUse(true) // Important for Android 13

// Creating wifi config
val wifiConfiguration = WifiConfiguration()
wifiConfiguration.enterpriseConfig = enterpriseConfig

wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration)
```

It works fine for android 12, but In android 13 I'm facing with disabled [TOFU](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-tofu?hl=en) (Trust on first usage) and this scheme is not working anymore. I almost solved this problem adding `enableTrustOnFirstUse` [option](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiEnterpriseConfig#enableTrustOnFirstUse(boolean)):

```
enterpriseConfig.enableTrustOnFirstUse(true)
```

But now I have to approve certificate on the phone before connection setup:

[image: test]

So in android 13 I cannot setup wifi network via my device owner app without user approve, but I could do this in android 12.

Is there any way to disable this approving popup?

P.S. Also, I've found two new options in WifiEnterpriseConfig:

```
trust_on_first_use: false
user_approve_no_ca_cert: false
```

First one can be disabled by `enableTrustOnFirstUse`, but the second one is [private](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/modules/Wifi/framework/java/android/net/wifi/WifiEnterpriseConfig.java;l=1738;drc=afc0f048f4f0ec407d217b86fc704405a1f324ec;bpv=0;bpt=1) and it seems like the second option is the reason of approving popup.